# Jogar valores em um array

Tags: php

Estou tentando jogar alguns valores em uma variável de sessão para posteriormente usa-la em um carrinho de compra, mas não estou conseguindo, os valores são o `id` e a `quantidade`.
O que fiz foi isso:

O formulário:

```html
<form method="get" action="addtocart.php">
<div class="product-quantity">
 <span>Quantity:</span> 
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $prodr['id']; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="quant" value="1">
</div>
<div class="shop-btn-wrap">
 <input type="submit" class="button btn-small" value="Add to Cart">
</div>
</form>
```

```
session_start();

if(isset($_GET) && !empty($_GET)){

    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $quant = $_GET['quant'];

    if (isset($quant) && !empty($quant))    { 
          $quant = $_GET['quant']; 
        } else { 
          $quant = 1;
    }

    $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = array("quantity" => $quant);   
    print_r($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
    exit;

    header('location: cart.php');

} else {
    header('location: cart.php');
}
```

As variáveis `$id` e `$quant` possuem valores, mas quando tendo exibir pelo `print_r()` não é exibido nada.

Conforme sugestão, segue resultado dos testes:

```
print_r($_GET);
Array ( [id] => 21 [quant] => 1 )
```

```
print_r($_SESSION);
Array ( [cart] => 1 [id] => Array ( [19] => 19 ) [quanr] => Array ( [19] => 1 ) [quant] => Array ( [19] => 1 ) )
```

Nesse segundo `print_r` apareceu esse `[quanr]` que não tem nada a ver e nem sei de onde ele veio.

Comment: Tem certeza que está enviando via GET?

Comment: Sim, esta sendo enviado por GET e possuem valores.

Comment: Estranho. Testei aqui com um formulário simples e funcionou normal.

Comment: `print_r($_GET);` e `print_r($_SESSION);` depois da primeira linha dão o que ?

Comment: O que exatamente acontece? Se entrar na condição, deveria exibir o resultado de `print_r`, caso contrário será redirecionado. Qual das duas ocorre? Aproveitando o contato, por quê utilizar `&` ao invés de `&&` na condição?

Comment: Dá um `session_destroy()` e começa os testes de novo. Parece que você está acumulando muito *lixo* na sessão de erros de digitação anteriores.